# Syntax error in update data sql query

Tags: php, mysql

beginner in php and having a lot of trouble nailing down my syntax error for an update data query. Here is the query.

```
    $sethere = "UPDATE `".$_currentclass."` 
    SET `".$_date."` = 1 
    WHERE studentid = `".$_idNum."`";
```

Error I'm getting just says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use at line 1."

Should be noted that the SET line is changing a boolean value which defaults to 0, and I want to change it to 1. I've tried tons of different permutations with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, since it's much safer. Are you using `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*` or `pdo`?

Comment: remove the backticks from $_idNum variable

Comment: try this- `$sethere = "UPDATE ".$_currentclass." SET ".$_date." = 1  WHERE studentid = ".$_idNum;`  and do `echo $sethere;` and run this query in mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Removing the backticks from $_idNum did it, thanks so much for your guys help, and I will look into using Prepared Statements, like I said, I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use backticks(**`**) for value section .

```
$sethere = "UPDATE `".$_currentclass."` 
SET `".$_date."` = 1 
WHERE studentid = ".$_idNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sethere = "UPDATE table_name SET col_name= 1 where studentid='$value'";
```

the error you are getting because you are not using the syntax according to the sql version. let me what version of php and sql you use

Comment: What version of mysql allows back ticks around the values?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sethere = "UPDATE ".$_currentclass."
SET ".$_date." = 1 
WHERE studentid = ".$_idNum;
```